# JS web scraping using puppeteer, getting this error: (node:12121) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: src.jsonValue is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, web, web-scraping, puppeteer

**Hello All**,
I'm trying to scrape something using puppeteer and for some reason getting the following error msg.

```
(node:12121) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: src.jsonValue is not a function
    at scrapeProduct (/Users/jesse/Documents/scraper/scrapers.js:12:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:12121) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12121) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Any ideas?

I am very new to node, which could be my issue. I don't have much code created yet, I was only trying to grab an image first for testing. Here is what i have so far.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  const [el] = await page.$x(
    '//*[@id="grandexchange"]/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[1]/img'
  );
  const src = el.getProperty("src");
  const srcTxt = await src.jsonValue();

  console.log({ srcTxt });
  await browser.close();
}

scrapeProduct(
  "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Uncut+sapphire/viewitem?obj=1623"
);
```

This is my second attempt. I was trying to also pull an Amazon.com book cover image. Got the same error msg.

Thanks for your replies!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `getProperty` returns a promise, so it should be `await el.getProperty("src")`
2. Always make sure you wait for the element to appear on the page. Use `await page.waitForXPath()` for xpath and `await page.waitForSelector()` for selectors.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="grandexchange"]/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[1]/img');
  const [el] = await page.$x(
    '//*[@id="grandexchange"]/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[1]/img'
  );
  const src = await el.getProperty('src');
  const srcTxt = await src.jsonValue();

  console.log({ srcTxt });
  await browser.close();
}

scrapeProduct(
  "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/Uncut+sapphire/viewitem?obj=1623"
);
```